# How to delete encrypted cookies on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rspec-rails

I'm trying to delete cookies set by

```
cookies.encrypted['something'] = 'a thing'
```

in a rspec file
but
`cookies.encrypted.delete` does not exist, I've checked on the docs, and `cookies.delete['something']` just delete non-encrypted cookies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An encrypted cookie is just a cookie whose [*value* is encrypted](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html). It's still a cookie like any other, and can be deleted in the same way. Simply use

```
cookies.delete('something')
```